# How to remove GPG verification for connecting with a remote Git repository?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, gnupg

I used to have a **GPG verification for secure connection** between a server and a remote Git repository hosted in a private **Gitlab** server. I had to change my credentials, and when I renewed them the **password-less connection with the remote repository stopped working**, even after following all the steps to regenerate the [SSH](https://alya.gitlab.bsc.es/help/user/ssh.md) and [GPG](https://alya.gitlab.bsc.es/help/user/project/repository/gpg_signed_commits/index.md) keys. The issue is that each time I try to communicate with the remote repository, I still get the following message as if the communication is still GPG-encrypted (even though I tried reseting my GPG ID multiple times):

```
myaccount@myserver.com:~> git clone https://alya.gitlab.myserver.com/myrepo/myrepo.git test
Cloning into 'test'...
gpg: encrypted with ELG key, ID 73F3BF2F
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
Username for 'https://myrepo.gitlab.myserver.com':
```

**Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?** I'd like to just use SSH if possible.

I also:

1. Updated the corresponding key-pairs on the Gitlab settings when regenerating the SSH and GPG keys, and called `git config --global user.signingkey <ID>` to point to the new key.
2. Tried reloading the gpg-agents by calling:

```
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

But got the following message:

```
gpg-connect-agent: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
```

Comment: `git clone https[...]` it looks like you're using an HTTPS address, which would require you to provide username/password. Use an SSH address to use SSH. As far as I know, GPG and git only mix when creating commits, so gpg should not be involved when just trying to clone a repo.

Comment: @sytech it looks as if the OP is using some sort of gpg-based credentials cache; the error comes when git tries to get credentials for the remote repository (and fails). @david without knowing more about your setup I'm not sure how much we can help. What are you using as a credentials store? Does `gpg` work correctly when run from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, @larsks -- learn something new every day :)

Comment: Thank you very much @systech and larsks. I could finally fix this by erasing and resetting my .gitconfig! I'm using https because of some restrictions I don't control on the server I work on. Larsks, I'm not sure you were asking for this, but I'm storing my credentials in RSA (id_rsa.pub). GPG did work correctly from the command line.